# How to build several objects while adding association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cocoon-gem

Rails 4.2.1, Ruby 2.2.1
Relations are:

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :translations,      dependent: :destroy  
  has_many :custom_properties, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :languages,         through: :translations
  has_many :options,           through: :custom_properties
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :custom_properties, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :translations,      reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

class CustomProperty < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
  has_many :options, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :custom_property_translations, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :custom_property_translations, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

class CustomPropertyTranslation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :custom_property
  belongs_to :language
end


class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :custom_property
  has_many :option_translations, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :option_translations, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

class OptionTranslation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :option
  belongs_to :language
end
```

In region form I'm using `cocoon` for nested fields.

```
  = f.simple_fields_for :custom_properties do |custom_property|
    = render 'custom_property_fields', f: custom_property
  .links
    = link_to_add_association 'add property', f, :custom_properties
```

And nested form for `CustomPropertyTranslation` and `OptionTranslation`.

```
= f.simple_fields_for :custom_property_translations do |custom_property_translation|
      = render 'custom_property_translation_fields', f: custom_property_translation
  .links
    = link_to_add_association t('.add_translation'), f, :custom_property_translations
```

I wan't to automatically build several `CustomPropertyTranslation` and `OptionTranslation` depending on how many languages are the region has.

I tried to use `after_initialize` callback to build necessary associations but it worked only for existing custom properties. How do I build several associations at once on click `add translation` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `count` key in `html_options` of `link_to_add_association` helper to determine how many new objects you want to create

```
= f.simple_fields_for :custom_property_translations do |custom_property_translation|
      = render 'custom_property_translation_fields', f: custom_property_translation
  .links
    = link_to_add_association t('.add_translation'), f, :custom_property_translations, {count: 3}
```

More on the available options here: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/blob/be59abd99027b0cce25dc4246c86d60b51c5e6f2/lib/cocoon/view_helpers.rb

Comment: Ok. Can I somehow provide values?
If I create translations that equal to the size of `region.languages` there is no reason to not lock the select tag.

Comment: you can provide the value you want to `count` and it'll render the specified objects, I can't quite get what you mean by "there's no reason to lock the select tag" ?

Comment: Suppose we have 3 languages in the region. When I click `add translation` link I see 3 pairs of inputs (select tag of language and text field of translation) added (because `{ count: @region.languages.size }`). Can I also provide values to select tag? Because there will be always 1 language per translation

Comment: I think something like that will be in `_custom_property_translation_fields` partial where you initialize the select with what you want, you can also do this initialization in the `build` function